# How do I use a shortcut to comment out code automatically in Textmate?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Is there a shortcut to highlight and comment code in textmate, rather than putting in the comments manually?

Comment: forgot! accepted now! thanks! :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have the `Source` bundle installed:

```
⌘/
```

[image: Comment in TextMate]

If you don't, go to `TextMate` > `Preferences` > `Bundles` and check `Source`.

Comment: To find this in the help assumes you have the 'Source' bundle installed.

Answer (score 8):

> ⌘/

comment/uncomment selection

Answer (score 3):

shift + ⌘ + 7 or instead 7 the key with the slash "/"