# How to comment or uncomment code in Textmate 2

Tags: textmate2

How do I comment or uncomment code in Textmate 2?

I came across [How do I use a shortcut to comment out code automatically in Textmate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256834/how-do-i-use-a-shortcut-to-comment-out-code-automatically-in-textmate) , but it's for Textmate 1.x, and "Bundles" > "Source" > "Comments" doesn't have "Comment line".

I'm using TextMate 2.0-beta.7.1.

I recall disabling <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> because it was causing problems while working on Rails apps, but I assumed that would just disable the keyboard shortcut, not the ability to comment and uncomment lines.

Answer (score 1):

In TextMate `2.0.19` you can comment, or uncomment, a line or selection with the shortcut `Cmd (⌘) + /`.

If this shortcut doesn't work for you, you can do it like this :

1. Select `Bundles` in the menu bar
2. Select `Source`
3. Select `Comments`
4. Select `Comment line`

Happy coding

---

## **TIPS**

### *Define a new shortcut for comment or uncomment*

If the native shortcut doesn't work for you, define a new one like this :

1. Select `Bundles` in the menu bar
2. Select `Edit Bundles...`
3. Select `Source`
4. Select `Menu Actions`
5. Select `Comments`
6. Select `Comment Line / Selection`
7. Click on `Key Equivalent`
8. Type your shortcut
9. Close the Bundles editor
10. A prompt will ask you to confirm your changes
11. Test it!

### *Others useful shortcuts*

1. Insert Block Comment : `Option (Alt, ⌥) + Cmd (⌘) + /`
2. Insert Comment Banner: Select the word or text you want to use as a banner and `Ctrl (⌃) + Shift (⇧) + B`
3. Insert Comment Header ( This will insert the name of the script and some useful details): You have to define it  because in my case it was empty... I defined it with `Ctrl (⌃) + Shift (⇧) + N`

### *Use Help in TextMate*

1. Select `Help` in the menu bar
2. type "comment"

This will brings you directly to the option `comment line`. I suggest doing that first because in most cases, you will find the answer.

---

Comment: Both the shortcut and the menu command are launching a little box saying "Preparing Ruby: Please wait while ruby 1.8 is prepared for use..." and TextMate no longer responds until I use "TextMate > Quit TextMate" from the menu and restart it. It doesn't actually comment the code (JavaScript in my case). Please help!

Comment: @ADTC can you give more details about your OS version, your TextMate version?

Comment: macOS Ventura 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d), TextMate version 2.0.23

Answer (score 0):

Bundles -> Source -> Menu Actions -> Comments -> Comment Line

Is that what you're looking for?